# TortoiseHg 3.6.3 broke mercurial keyring?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-keyring

I upgraded to Tortoise 3.6.3 yesterday and now I am prompted every time I pull or push a repo.  The keyring is set properly, and my user name is in the url.

Any ideas on what may be wrong? Did 3.6.3 break keyring?

Comment: Why not ask the project directly? They have a [bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/?kind=bug&status=open).

Comment: Why not ask the project directly?  Godwin's Law, and because Stackoverflow has spoiled me!  I hate searching through a dozen different threads looking for the one and only one answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Issue 4401 "mercurial_keyring always asks for user/password"](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4401/mercurial_keyring-always-asks-for-user) from time of 3.6.2 closed as pure extension-specific and [contains solution](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4401/mercurial_keyring-always-asks-for-user#comment-24345064): don't use username in URL anymore

Here is what to put into .hg/hgrc:

```
[auth]
default.username=myname
default.prefix=http://myrepo
```

A good way to debug issues like this is to run merciural from the command line with the debug flag, as in:

```
hg pull --debug
```

This will clearly indicate if there are problems getting the repo, user name, and password.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: [A new version of TortoiseHG has been released](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) (3.8.3 at the time of writing) and fixes this issue: upgrading to latest version should be enough.**

I had this exact same problem and found [the following investigation article](https://hglabhq.com/blog/2016/2/7/investigation-mercurial-keyring-always-asking-for-username-and-password)  to be quite helpful to better understand what't going on (I'm not the author, BTW).

To cut it short, it seems a bug of the **mercurial_keyring extension** v1.0.1, introduced in TortoiseHG 3.6.2, which also appears to be fixed in v**1.1.1**.

If you're into Python compiling, it should be possible to upgrade it manually *into* TortoiseHG by getting it from its [official bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial_keyring/), compile it and manually place it into TortoiseHG's /lib/library.zip file (backup it beforehand might be wise): if you're not, you have 2 options:

1) clone the bitbucket repo to your HDD and then configure your Mercurial installation to use the new version of that extension module by writing the following in your C:\Users\USERNAME\mercurial.ini file (which was what I did):

```
[extensions]
mercurial_keyring = /path/to/mercurial_keyring/mercurial_keyring.py
```

(Notice: you might also have to put the path in your PATH or PYTHONPATH env variable, depending if you already have Python and/or Mercurial installed on your machine).

2) wait for the next TortoiseHG release that will contain the updated version.